# Show docstring from resolver in GraphiQL [graphene]

Tags: graphene-python

I faced with a small issue while trying to add description to a resolver in graphene (to be able to fetch this data in GraphiQL). Mostly the problem is that I want to be able to fetch docstring from resolver *directly*, rather than specify it as a `description` parameter of a `Field` in `Query` class.

Here is a small snippet with explanation:

```
from graphene import ObjectType, String, Field

class Person(ObjectType):
    full_name = String()

    def resolve_full_name(parent, info):
        return f"{parent.first_name} {parent.last_name}"

class Query(ObjectType):
    me = Field(Person)

    def resolve_me(parent, info):
        """
        I want to display this docstring description in GraphiQL, 
        rather than use `description` attribute, eg. 
           me = Field(Person, description="Blah-blah")
        """
        return get_human(name="Luke Skywalker")
```

Are there any workarounds and ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: I don't think this will be easy.  You could try subclassing `ObjectType`  -- start here https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/8e7d76bbce3eb8755bf4f3beba8b9d8b026c6424/graphene/types/objecttype.py